# Passing callback function to labelFormatter in highchart legend in typescript

Tags: highcharts, typescript, angular, callback, highcharts-ng

I am trying to use HighCharts in Angular2 using typescripts.

I am trying to format my legend text, with image to show up next to it. HighChart legend has labelFormatter property to provide callback function.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter

> Callback function to format each of the series' labels. The this
>   keyword refers to the series object, or the point object in case of
>   pie charts. By default the series or point name is printed.

But I dont know how to pass callback function in typescripts to labelFormatter property.

```
updateChart(): void {
    let newOptions = {
        legend: {
            useHTML: true,
            itemMarginBottom: 10,
            enabled: true,
            floating: true,
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            labelFormatter: (s) => this.getLegendLabel(s),
            y: 35
       }
    }
}

getLegendLabel(seriesDetails) {
    console.log(seriesDetails);
}
```

But I am getting undefined for **seriesDetails** object.

and if I used **this** keyword anywhere it refers to that component rather than series information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter):

> Callback function to format each of the series' labels. The this
>   keyword refers to the series object, or the point object in case of
>   pie charts. By default the series or point name is printed.

I guess you've got wrong "this" in the fat arrow function. IMHO the simpliest way just follow documentation syntax ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/labelformatter/)):

```
labelFormatter: function () {
    return this.name + ' (click to hide)';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your code like this:

```
updateChart(): void {
    let newOptions = {
        legend: {
            useHTML: true,
            itemMarginBottom: 10,
            enabled: true,
            floating: true,
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            labelFormatter: this.getLegendLabel,
            y: 35
       }
    }
}

getLegendLabel() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

It will produce the following JS code and will work as you expect (Test is my classname):

```
Test.prototype.updateChart = function () {
    var newOptions = {
        legend: {
            useHTML: true,
            itemMarginBottom: 10,
            enabled: true,
            floating: true,
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            labelFormatter: this.getLegendLabel,
            y: 35
        }
    };
};
Test.prototype.getLegendLabel = function () {
    console.log(this);
};
```